# how to dynamically add a class to a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

1)how  to dynamically add a class to a paragraph?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change an element's CSS class with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

The short answer: `document.getElementById("MyElement").className += " MyClass"`

The long answer: [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the *[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)* of jQuery:

```
$('p').addClass('myClass yourClass');
```

For Dojo you can use [*addClass*](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.3/dojo.addClass):

```
dojo.addClass(dijit.byId('myTextBox').domNode, 'myClass');
```

Comment: I cant use jquery, am using dojo

Answer (score 1):

look at the [docs for dojo.addClass](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo) (look under "method summary" then click on dojo.addClass)

**Example 1**
Add a class to some node:

```
dojo.addClass("someNode", "anewClass");
```

**Example 2**
Add two classes at once:

```
dojo.addClass("someNode", "firstClass secondClass");
```

**Example 3**
Add two classes at once (using array):

```
dojo.addClass("someNode", ["firstClass", "secondClass"]);
```

**Example 4**
Available in `dojo.NodeList` for multiple additions

```
dojo.query("ul > li").addClass("firstLevel");
```

Answer (score 0):

**in html:**

`<p id="myparagraph">My paragraph</p>`

**in javascript:**

```
function ChangeColor() {
var label;
label = document.getElementById("myparagraph");
label.className  = "yourclass";

}

ChangeColor();
```